# How to access a dictionary value inside a list of custom objects?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object

I have the following toy object:

```
x = [Agg({   'name': 'James',
     'class': 'calculus1',
     'avg': 90}),
     Agg({   'name': 'Mary',
     'class': 'calculus1',
     'avg': 99})]
```

So the outer bracket [ indicates this is a list of the datatype Agg <s>pandas series?</s> (no, it is a class object - class Agg - see comments).  The outer parenthesis ( indicates to me the Agg is a <s>tuple</s> class object, and the { with key values indicates a dictionary.  I want to get the key values of 'avg' into a new list, **avgs** such that `avgs=[90,99,50,100]` I think the answer involves a list comprehension along the lines of `z = [x[0] for a in x]`, but I don't understand the syntax to access Agg.  How do I do this?

Comment: This is 2 objects actually(x and y). What exactly is Agg? Is this equal with pandas.DataFrame()?

Comment: I deleted Y, thanks  - it wasn't relevant.  As far as what the Agg is, I'm not sure - I've never seen it before.  This is how the object displays out.  Maybe it is a pandas Series, but I am not familiar with it, hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that Agg is a function that returns a pandas.Series, like below:

```
import pandas as pd

def Agg(x):
    return pd.Series(x)
```

Given that, you can easily get avg values with the following:

```
result=[i.avg for i in x]

>>>print(result)

[90, 99]
```

(If you could provide more info about Agg, it would be more specific)

Comment: Just tried it.  Comes back `TypeError: 'Agg' object is not subscriptable`  Looking into it a bit more, I think that Agg is a named entity of some sort.  I can force x into being a dataframe by entering `x.df` but `x[0].df` throws a `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'df'`.  I just realized I am able to access individual fields by ```x[0].avg ``` - see your response.

Comment: instead of `result=[i['avg'] for i in x]` , this works perfectly : `result=[i.avg for i in x]`   Thank you for your help

Comment: Great! Can you please accept some of the answers if your problem was resolved? Cheers

Comment: sure - I would just ask you edit from brackets to .obj in your 2nd code block answer please.

Comment: I think I need to modify the question title as Agg represents a custom object instead of a tuple.  That's why we could access it with the . period!

Comment: You can add the code of Agg object, it would help the readers of the question

Comment: OK turns out that Agg was a CLASS object with defined  ,name, .class, and .avg objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop
Ex:
for i in x:
for j in x[i]
I think this ll help access the dictionary.